# how to make a z-depth AND height pass?

Tags: compositing-nodes

Struggling to work out how to make a depth AND height pass, so I can use them in compositing an animation of a city.

Depth is easy...height, not so...

Is there some way to mix a vertical gradient with a mist pass to get this result? Or is there a different way?

I am trying to get the effect of a denser mist at lower levels.

Let me know if i need to clarify further.

Comment: can explain more than this ?

Comment: You want the mist denser at lower altitudes?

Comment: yes, but this also needs to work with an animation , so must still be effective if we move through a scene.

Comment: Related: [How to make low lying fog](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43600/low-lying-fog-bounding-object-rendering-as-solid/43648#43648)

Answer (score 9):

***Basic idea :*** render additional layer with overriding material which assign a grayscale value based on the point height  , use this layer as height pass

***Details :***

create the overriding material that will replace all materials in the height pass as follows :

[image]

setup an the height pass to use the override material :

[image]

in the compositor use the color output of the Height layer as a height pass :

[image]

after compositing here is the result :
**no height :**
[image]
 **with height :**
[image]

Comment: thanks thats looks interesting, guessing I can swap the math for a colour ramp, will give this a try.

Comment: @user3471  I guess you can , also there is a map value node you can use

Comment: Having trouble mixing this with my mist pass than I am using for depth.What I need to do is only have mist at far and low levels, however when try to mix the height map and depth I get the mist at the front not back.Maybe i should be using an transparent material  instead of the black?

Comment: @user3471 so you mean no gradient mist (constant from depth a to b ) along the depth  ?

Comment: I think i may have figured it now. Because the gradient for the height is on the actually meshes unlike the z-dpeth or mist pass it does not effect the sky or background. This was creating a weird effect when mixing the height layer with my mist pass.So on the height layer i added an alpha over node with a white background  and this seems to work.

Comment: @user3471 glad you solved this , I didn't realize that ( my test file is too simple )  feel free to edit my post to include this solution