# Low lying fog bounding object rendering as solid

Tags: objects, smoke-simulation

I'm trying to make a low lying fog, and the box I used as a boundary on the smoke rendered as a solid object, blocking everything inside it.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/24424/1245. Probably the smoke domain doesn't have volumetric material.

Comment: Or use the simple mist but with this trick: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28648/how-to-make-a-z-depth-and-height-pass That would save a lot of render time, as it doesn't use volumetrics.

Answer (score 14):

As an alternative to smoke you can use volume scattering.

In an example like this:

[image]

Add a mesh that uses a volume scatter node as the volume.

[image]

Using a gradient and a color ramp you can control the height and density of the fog.

[image]

Using additional textures to affect the transparency of the volume scattering you can get a less homogeneous mist.

[image]

To move the fog animate the mapping used on the textures.

[image]

[image]

Here's the file: [image]

Comment: For a different solution using the compositor and Z pass see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28648/how-to-make-a-z-depth-and-height-pass

Comment: Ooh wow.
Nodes seem to be rather important... I think  I need to get to learning them. 
So what the node does is make the box there but not?

Comment: If you look at the node on the far right you'll see it has no surface, only volume. Note that this is not a smoke simulation, but a volume shader on a regular mesh (used as a domain for voumetrics).