# How to make moving fog

Tags: node-editor, smoke-simulation, volumetrics

I tried the mist effect and the smoke simulation but didn't like the results. What I want to achieve is a static fog like the fog in this picture.
[image]

Steady but also moving slowly on the surface of lake.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43600/low-lying-fog-bounding-object-rendering-as-solid To make the fog move just animate the coordinates of the texture

Comment: it is exactly what i was looking for ..thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crate an object that will act as domain and assign it some volume scattering as detailed on [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/43648/1853)

Then use some texture to make the fog less homogeneous, and animate the mapping for it.

[image]

[image]