# Is it possible to control cycles mist pass height like blender internal?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, render-passes

In the blender manual about the mist pass, it is explained that the height intensity of the mist pass can be controlled. This gives the effect that it is more 'cloudy' on the bottom for instance than the top.

[Blender manual on mist pass](https://docs.blender.org/manual/fi/dev/render/blender_render/world/mist.html)

[image: Image of blender internal options]

Is this effect possible in cycles with the mist pass?

Comment: Also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43600/low-lying-fog-bounding-object-rendering-as-solid/43648#43648