# How to create a Low lying fog in fields slowly rising up?

Tags: materials, node-editor, shaders

I wan't to create a Meadow Scene and there is a lot of low lying detailed fog that is moving and rising very slowly like these in reference pictures
If I adds simple principled volume shader it will not have such details like this mist is rised to some level or height in picture 1 after that it disappears

Mainly Picture 1 is the correct reference picture for the result what i want

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

how can i create that can any one show me the node setup ?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43600/low-lying-fog-bounding-object-rendering-as-solid

Comment: Let me Add some Reference Pictures in this question so that question is clear

Comment: if you want to use a very simple trick you could just create planes with gradient effects which mixes Emission and Transparency and give it a bit of noise