# Smoke Simulation Render Issue

Tags: smoke-simulation

I was trying to render a rocket takeoff, but where I have my domain set is just a gray box on the final render?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Low lying fog bounding object rendering as solid](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43600/low-lying-fog-bounding-object-rendering-as-solid)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to add *color emission* to your object by using an *Attribute* node with the property `flame` spelled exactly like that.

Then connect that node to a *ColorRamp*. Adjust the color ramp settings to be the color of the flame, and then attach that to an *Emission* shader.

Set the power of the *Emission* shader to 5, then connect that to the *Add* shader in the Cycles node setup for the smoke domain.