# How do I fill a room with mist (smoke) in blender cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, physics

I'm trying to fill a room with humid mist, and cannot get the smoke domain to change from grey to any color. I also tried to just use volume scatter within the world nodes and it requires too much ram for my computer. Any advice on just making really minor, atmospheric mist?

Here's my new node setup. It works, but cannot get the color to change from grey to transparent white. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Delete all the extra nodes. As a rule don't add complexity until you know what each of those additions is doing. All you need is a volume scatter node. Volume scatter is like suspended particles on the air, Lower the density so that the air will be more "transparent". Usually a value of 0.1 or smaller works fine, but play with it until you are satisfied. But don't add more nodes until you understand what each one is doing. It is easier to find the answer to one problem if you keep the variables under control. The more combinations you add, the harder it will be to control the result

Answer (score 4):

Add a big cube that surrounds the room (there is no need to set it as domain of a smoke simulation) and use a Volume Scatter node connected to the Volume output of the Material output Node. Unplug anything that is connected to the surface socket.

[image]

like in this example:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqmki.jpg]

and this post:

[Low lying fog bounding object rendering as solid](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43600)

Comment: in your screenshot you've plugged the Volume Scatter into the Material Output Surface input, I guess you wanted to plug it into the Volume input?

Comment: This is great, thank you both for the help!

Comment: thanks for the edit.

Comment: I updated the post with my current node setup. I can't seem to get it to be more of a white mist, just the standard grey smoke displays

Comment: If you are getting grey, you probably need to increase the intensity of your lights. What is gray? What is black? What is white? it is all relative to the amount of light on the scene.