# How to create moving, dynamic/animated fog/clouds?

Tags: volumetrics

I watched tutorials on how to create fog within bounding boxes, but the fog is static.
I'm trying to create a scene of an airplane where the camera is looking down on the clouds, and the clouds should be moving.  I was going to try and make the clouds in a similar way as I made the fog (with bounding boxes) but is there a way to make the clouds move?  The airplane is going to fly through the clouds so it's important that they are 3d and not just a plane.
Is there a better way than using bounding boxes?

Comment: How did you make the fog effect?

Comment: You could try noise and density with a principled volume, while changing the vector

Comment: Animate the coordinates for a texture used in the volume scattering and/or the settings for a noise texture: See the bottom of this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43600/low-lying-fog-bounding-object-rendering-as-solid

Answer (score 1):

As Yohello says you could use the *Principled Volume* and plug it into the *Volume* socket of the *Material Output*. Here is a basic way to do it (perhaps not the most realistic solution though, but you'll find other ones on youtube or maybe someone will propose here?):

- Create a basic elongated shape, subdivide it a bit, give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier.
- Create this node chain: *Texture Coordinate > Mapping > Noise Texture > ColorRamp*.
- Plug the *Noise Texture* into a *Vector > Displacement* node to give it a bit of 3D relief (don't forget to enable the *Displacement > Displacement Only* option in the *Properties* panel > *Material > Settings > Surface*).
- Plug the *Noise* into the *Density* socket of the *Principled Volume*.
- Now play with the *Location* values of the *Mapping* node in order to make the cloud shape evolve through time.

[image]