# Blender 2.8 Using z height (Depth) gradient to reduce mist intensity

Tags: render-layers

I'm trying to find something for 2.8 but struggling.

I want to use the z height (depth on render layer?) to reduce the intensity of mist (composite layer) exponentially as height increases.

Currently, the mist render layer setup only affects intensity based on distance from camera.

The following tut shows how it could be done but it doesn't seem to have the same effect in 2.8.

[image: shader setup mist pass]

[how to make a z-depth AND height pass?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28648/how-to-make-a-z-depth-and-height-pass?noredirect=1&lq=1&newreg=f0736aa1c57b45b1bf2e882ef018fb44)

Can anyone help with the node setup please?

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43600/low-lying-fog-bounding-object-rendering-as-solid/43648#43648

Comment: Thanks - interesting approach.

Comment: The linked answer on your post is easy to do in 2.8. The only difference is that layers have changed to collections and view layers. But the same principles apply. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96463/where-is-the-layers-panel-in-blender-2-8/96465#96465

Comment: Ahhh - OK - it's a little confusing so let me work through it - thanks.

Comment: you need a Normalize node before the viewer node!